# Moving XML data in their respective tables in SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have a database named IMOS from which I'm extracting data from multiple tables in XML format using VB scripting. Now, using XML data I wanted to move XML data in SQL (in their respective tables). For example, there is employee table data in XML format, I wanted to move all the data of XML file in their respective tables in SQL. How can I do that?

Comment: Guys any idea??

Comment: Please add more details to your question: it is very hard to help you without further information. For example: post a sample of your xml and the structure of the corresponding table. Are the xml documents stored in files or elsewhere? Do you want to import data from xml using VB or TSQL? What have you already tried? In case of doubt check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) out.